# CMake imported library include_directories before other ones

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake project with an IMPORTED library which has a include directory which must be used before the include directories of the executable.

I tried the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test_cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)

#Librarry
add_library(lib SHARED IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(lib SYSTEM BEFORE INTERFACE ./lib_inc/)
set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_IMPLIB "lib.lib")

add_executable(test_cmake main.cpp)
target_include_directories(test_cmake AFTER PRIVATE include)
target_link_libraries(test_cmake PRIVATE lib)
```

But at least with the generator "Visual Studio 9 2008" the directory "include" in used before "lib_inc". Does anybody know a way to modify the imported lib so that there include will be the first?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know a way to modify the imported lib so that there include will be the first?

**The answer is no.** Compiler command lines are computed by walking the DAG of linked libraries and placing the merged interface properties in (de-duplicated) *pre-order* starting with the "top" target. So there is no interface property that can do exactly what you want.

> I have a [...] library which has a include directory which must be used before the include directories of the executable.

Frankly, this is a really dubious requirement. The library cannot know to which executables it will be linked so it cannot be a *requirement* to *override* its linkers' (as in "linker" and "linkee", not `ld`) include paths. Similarly, if this library `L` were a dependency of a static library `S`, and an executable `E` linked to `S`, what should happen with the "before" include dirs of `L`? Should they override `E`'s? If so, that would be a truly confusing behavior, whereby no target can ever trust its own headers to be used, ever.

So this is not only *not available*, it's pretty dubious that it ever *should* be available. This just isn't a coherent semantics for property propagation.

Comment: I am talking about include directories, not linker directories, where, I think, it is more common that the order is relevant.

Comment: @gerum - I did not say anything about linker directories as in `ld`. I was talking about include directory propagation from linkee to link-_er_ (i.e. the target doing the linking). Think "caller" and "callee". I agree the terminology is confusing.